# PowerBI Data Model and Slicers for Many-to-Many-to-Many too Many Over Time

Tags: powerbi, many-to-many, relationship, data-modeling

tl;dr one table with tons of rows representing product records for each date from different product families. I need two charts, one for each of two product families. Each must update from a slicer of the products and another of customer demographics, but selecting products form one family in the slicer causes the other family's chart to go blank because of data model. Looking for ideas on how to better model this data to do what stakeholders want: bi-directional, many-to-many, multi-slicer, updates two charts.

I have a fact table in PowerBI that represents products under our customer accounts, one row for each record for each day. In the OLTP layer this is arranged as follows:

```
customer account
    |__product family A
         |_product type 01
         |_product type 02
         |_product type ...
    |__product family B
         |_product type 01
         |_product type 02
         |_product type ...
```

In each account there may be 0 or many product and product families of each type. There are a few dozen product types but only 2 product families, just simplifying for the example.

The fact table I have has a row for each product for each day roughly in the form of:

```
date, customer account, product family, product type, product unique ID, some other aggregates like sales total etc., customer demo-specifics
```

Basically all of the identifying fields - the non-aggregates - repeat, one row for each date+account+product fmaily+product type+product UID+and so on. This way I have the aggregate values for each date, for each product specifically, by account and associated demographics.

Now, my charts are displaying the aggregate values over time, the slicers allow users to slice along product types for the aggregates over time, but also the customer demographics. I have one chart for each product family. Those update just fine independently.

However, my stakeholders want this scenario to work - select a product from family A, the charts for product family B should update to reflect the aggregates over time of products in family B that accounts holding selected products from family A have. If that makes sense.

Basically, they want to be able to slice along those customers with product family A/product type and then see the chart for product family B update as well (assuming those customers do have products in family B). This also needs to work in reverse. Slice along B, family A chart updates.

My current behavior is that the opposite product family chart goes blank. This is because I'm filtering the product aggregates for it and also applying more aggregates to force distinct account records, if that makes sense.

Because of this data model, I have multiple rows for each account on each date. I considered just leaving out the unique accounts for each date and aggregating into each date for each product, then the relationships would be on date. The problem, my stakeholders also want to be able to slice along the customer demographics too. So they might want to select customer demographic X, product family A, product 03 and obviously see the family a chart reflect those selections, but also see family b chart reflect the b family products those customers have.

Complicating things further, the stakeholders want the product family/product slicer to contain both families. I almost need something like a SQL self join for these charts.

I've also tried using separate fact tables and relating along the customer account, but bi directional many-to-many relationships didn't work.

Comment: I see a lot of text but no questions. What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.